# where clause not working for varchar field as expected in SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, where-clause

I have a stored procedure(working dynamically) which accepts many parameters and one such parameter is @lAmountValue which is filter out the records based on the field Min. I have used the below where clause to filter out the records based on the value of Min. But it is retrieving records incorrectly where it is fetching the null values, empty strings along with my criteria and also values greater than the specified value(when searching with EqualTo criteria). The same filter is working correctly for numeric fields but not for varchar fields. Min is a varchar field and the column values in the table can contain Null, empty strings, numbers and strings. Please help to find out the error in my where clause.

```
if @lComparer = 'EqualTo'               
    Set @Query= @Query +'and TN.Min is not null and TN.Min !='' and cast(TN.Min as varchar(30)) = '''' + CAST(@lAmountValue as varchar(30)) + '''' '            
else if @lComparer = 'GreaterThan' 
    Set @Query= @Query +'and TN.Min is not null and TN.Min !='' and cast(TN.Min as varchar(30)) > '''' + CAST(@lAmountValue as varchar(30)) + '''' '    
else if @lComparer = 'LessThan'                                 
    Set @Query= @Query +'and TN.Min is not null and TN.Min !='' and cast(TN.Min as varchar(30)) < '''' + CAST(@lAmountValue as varchar(30)) + '''' '
```

Comment: Have you tried something like: `CAST(' + @lAmountValue + 'as varchar(30))` - depends on where your variable is located...

Comment: Additionally you can't use > or < on a varchar value,  how can a string be greater than another string as they are not numeric values...

Comment: @Hex if you're first comment were correct, then the OP would be seeing an error along the lines of `Must declare the scalar variable "@lAmountValue ".` As for you're second, yes, you can use `>` and`<` with a string. Try `SELECT CASE WHEN 'B' > 'A' THEN 'Works!' END;`. For operators like these each individual letter, in it's ordinal position is compared. So, for example `'AAAZ' < 'AAZ'` and `'19' < '2'`.

Comment: Ah right, thank you for clarifying that. However judging by their variable names, "TN.Min" and "AmountValue" I'd assume they are attempting to compare numeric values.

Comment: Yes, I agree @Hex. To the OP, you probably want to try and provide some sample data to go with this. But we raise a good point in the above comments: `'19' < '2'` and `19 < 2` are not the same expression. The first expression with evaluate to TRUE, as the **`varchar`** `'19'` does have a lower value than `'2'`. On the other hand the **`integer`** `19` does not have a lower value than `2`, and so the expression will evaluate to FALSE. If you are comparing dates/numbers/etc, never convert these to string data types and compare; you'll likely get very odd results.

Comment: This link will give you advice on how to provide sample data. We'll also need a query to be able to use against that sample data: [Forum Etiquette: How to post a T-SQL Question](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/). We don't (necessarily) need all your tables, etc; a simplified version of your set up is fine as long as we can replicate your scenario.